# Comparing session username with text

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to check if the username on the session is equal to a username in mysql database.  Let's say the username admin is the only person allowed to see certain page.

Please can someone advise what is wrong with my piece of code?

```
<?php if($_SESSION["myusername"]=="admin"){?>
<a href="Stuff4Staff.php">Employee</a>
<?php }else{
?>
<a href="managerInterface.php">Manager</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the above code. What doesn't work? Did you initialize your session with `session_start()`?

Comment: Deceze and Dave, what is your solution? I am doing a coursework that says we have to separate pages for employee and manager. Manager is a more specific type of employee. My question is not about how silly the courseworks are is about sessions. I am learning php by myself, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you need `session_start()` and you also need to check session `isset`:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && $_SESSION["myusername"]=="admin"){
?>
    <a href="managerInterface.php">Manager</a>

<?php 
    }else{
?>
    <a href="Stuff4Staff.php">Employee</a>       
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: It gave me this error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ',' or ')' in /homes/iia0014/public_html/session.php on line 3

Comment: sorry i forgot a bracket ) i have edited my answer, refresh then copy paste it in to your script.

Comment: If this solved your problem please tick my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you start your session by placing the following above your current code:

```
session_start();
```

And it goes without saying to double check you're setting the variable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try strcmp (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)...

and make sure the session variable is set